# Validating List Control In-Place Edit

Tags: mfc

In my list control I have in place edit control.

On killfocus event of edit control I am validating the text.

My requirement is when clicking on scrollbar of listcontrol I should validate with old text(it should behave like esc key )

In my application when clicking on scrollbar of listcontrol the  killfocus event of edit control getting triggered and the text is getting validated with current text.

How to validate with old text?

Thanks.

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753).

Comment: @IInspectable  when to do validation for in place edit control in list control?

Comment: There's an answer to your question that explains precisely, when to do input validation.

Comment: In that link, they mentioned that for dialog validation should be done on ok button click but for my case I could not get any idea from that link.

Comment: That link also explains, what issues input validation causes when done during `WM_KILLFOCUS` handling. Those issues apply to your case just as well. I also commented, that you have received an answer, that shows a viable notification to do input validation.

Comment: in my case I am doing validation at WM_KILLFOCUS only. I don't know any other way.

Comment: Stop doing that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50209066/1889329) tells you when to validate instead. It also hints at how to revert invalid input to the initial entry.

Answer (score 3):

As you receive a `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` you also receive a [LVN_ENDLABELEDIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774814.aspx) notification. Return TRUE or FALSE according your needs.

Comment: To check the focus is on list control's scroll bar,I tried below code but the pScroll is always NULL.                                                                 CListCtrl* pList = ((CListCtrl*)GetParent());
CWnd* pScroll = PList->GetScrollBarCtrl(SB_VERT);                                                                                           how to get list control's scroll bar window's handle?

Comment: Scrollbars are embedded in the list control and don't have a different focus as the list control itself.

Comment: How to get list control's rectangle except header and scrollbar?

Comment: GetClientRect!? You are asking basics. This is not a forum to discuss any development. Please read the guidelines of SO and please inform yourself of the basics of windows programming.